# Force variable expansion on remote ssh server

Tags: ssh, sed

I am trying to replace a string in a file on a remote server:

```
ssh $login "
replacement=\`find . -name file\`;
sed -i -e 's/contact/\$replacement/g' path/file;
"
```

but I can't get the content of the $replacement variable to be used by sed. The example above prints `$replacement` in my file. I also tried

```
sed -i -e 's/contact/\"\$replacement\"/g' path/file;
```

but it just prints `"$replacement"`

What would be the correct syntax?

Comment: Probably relevant: [*Variable expansion and quotes within quotes*](https://superuser.com/q/1404244/432690).

Comment: You are using single quotes around the whole `sed` expression, including the variable expansion.  This will prevent the shell from expanding your variable.  Could you confirm that you want to replace the string `contact` in some file with the pathnames of a set of files?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in between single quotes $replacement isn't expanded.

In this case `sed -i -e "s/contact/$replacement/g" path/file;` should work.

Or this:

```
sed -i -e 's/nothing/'$replacement'/g' path/file;
```

Example:

```
$ echo "There's nothing there." > file 
$ cat file 
There's nothing there.
$ replacement=something 
$ sed -i -e 's/nothing/'$replacement'/g' file;
$ cat file
There's something there.
```

In response to Kusalananda's comment below: If replacement, being a path, contains slashes then you would have to pre-process it before you use it with sed:

```
replacement=$(sed 's@\/@\\\/@g' <<< "$replacement")
```

Comment: Note that `$replacement` may be a pathname, i.e. it may (will!) contain slashes.  Also, you should demonstrate running this on a remote machine using `ssh`.  Using `localhost` for testing would be enough.

Comment: So then there's a need to pre-process the replacement:
replacement=$(sed 's/\//\\\//g' <<< "$replacement")
or replacement=$(sed 's|\/|\\\/|g' <<< "$replacement")

Comment: `sed` can use almost any other character as delimiter instead of `/` in a substitution.  `sed 's@PATTERN@REPLACEMENT@'`, for example.  The only thing is to make sure it's not a character already in the pattern, or in the replacement.

Comment: That's better. The @ is certainly more readable than the | adjacent to the \.

Answer (score 1):

here documents are a good idea to explore when you're in quoting hell:

```
ssh "$login" <<'END_REMOTE'
    replacement=$(find . -name file)
    sed -i -e 's/contact/$replacement/g' path/file
END_REMOTE
```

The opening keyword for the heredoc is quoted, which means the whole heredoc is single quoted. Easier to read, no?